# Y coordinate of mbtiles is in descending order (tippecanoe, ogr2ogr)

Tags: ogr2ogr, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, offset

I want to convert a geojson to MVT and upload it to s3 to use it with Mapbox GLJS.

I tried this tutorial https://geovation.github.io/tippecanoe-directory-support.

With `tippecanoe --no-feature-limit --no-tile-size-limit --no-tile-compression --output-to-directory NamedPlace NamedPlace.json` I can convert my geojson to MVT.

I also tried ogr2ogr

```
ogr2ogr -f MVT mytileset source.gpkg -dsco MAXZOOM=10
```

But like in the tutorial the y coordinates are in descending order and I need ascending order. Mapbox wants to access coordinates that are not in the MVT.
[image]

Is there a way to change the order in Mapbox GLJS or a parameter in ogr2ogr/tippecanoe?

Also sometimes points are missing and sometimes it searches the wrong x axis.

Is it also maybe a projeection error?

Comment: MVT has by default TMS coordinates order. Why don't you use `"scheme": "tms"` option in MapBox GL JS vectir layer source defrinition? See https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/sources/